# using getElementByClassName in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to target `Safari(both mobile and desktop)` and append some styles for a class via `Javascript`.

This is how my code looks like.

```
(function safaristyles()
{
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/) && ! navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome/)) {
        var avt = document.getElementsByClassName("avatar");
        avt.style.border = "0" + "px";
        avt.style.padding = "0" + "px";
    }
})(this);
```

As I see it in `Webkit inspector`, this is the error I'm facing.

**Type Issue -
'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'avt.style.border = "0" + "px")**

I'm a beginner at JS stuff, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName("avatar");` will return you elements is a HTMLCollection of found elements.

so if you have just one item this would work

```
  avt[0].style.border = "0" + "px";
    avt[0].style.padding = "0" + "px";
```

if you have multiple items use a for loop.

here is a simple fiddle for something similar
http://jsfiddle.net/qjreK/1/

Check these out for more details

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_using.asp

Comment: Thank you so much! I just used a for loop, which loops from 0 to `avt.length` and it worked.

Comment: *will return you an array* not technically

Answer (score 0):

[`document.getElementsByClassName()`](http://devdocs.io/dom/document.getelementsbyclassname) returns a set of elements. If you want to change the style of a class, I see two good options:

1. Append a style tag with the new class style.
2. Make a loop and change each item of the `document.getElementsByClassName()`'s list.

I would recomment to **use the first method**, because it would allow you to add new elements with that class without needing to change it's style.

Answer (score 0):

The method getElementsByClassName just return the nodeList match that classname which you pass in, but not array.

You can convert this nodeList to array and set the single item's style

```
var avt = Array.prototype.slice.call(avt, 0);

avt[0].style.padding = "0px";
```

Comment: Converting it to a real array to use the next line in your example is pointless (you may want to suggest a loop or something).