# Alternative for classList and className

Tags: javascript

So I'm creating a page where i need some sort of class add on click of an element. My problem is className and classList both don't work in older IOS safari clients. Does anyone know an alternative to:

```
var answer = target.parentElement.querySelector('.icon');
answer.className = "answer-text";
```

or

```
var answer = target.parentElement.querySelector('.icon');
answer.classList.add('Active');
```

I can't seem to find any alternatives on the web.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Comment: According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_classlist_add_and_remove_multiple_arguments) `.classList.add(x)` should work on iOS Safari 7 and up. Do you have to support versions lower than that?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769563/using-getelementbyclassname-in-safari

Comment: @FahadSubzwari that's for `getElementsByClassName` not adding classes.

Comment: @VLAZ no unfortunately not and yes, the problem here is it needs to support versions lower than Safari 7. It would have been no problem otherwise :(

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class)

The property `attributes.class` is supported in Safari.
So you can write

```
answer.attributes.class.value = "answer-text";
```